# show crate dependency tree for a common crate with required version

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

***tl;dr*** I want to know the tree of dependencies that require a common crate *and **which version** of that common crate is requested by each dependency*

My project indirectly depends on crate `proc_macro2` from several direct dependencies. That is, multiple project dependencies use crate `proc_macro2`.
Crate `proc_macro2` [latest version is 1.0.63](https://docs.rs/proc-macro2/1.0.63/proc_macro2/). However, from the tree dependencies, rustc chooses to use version 1.0.52 .

The problem is [proc-macro2 version 1.0.52 fails to compile with the latest rust nightly](https://github.com/jtmoon79/super-speedy-syslog-searcher/issues/151).

So I want to know: which dependencies are requesting version 1.0.52 of `proc_macro2`?

I can use `cargo tree --invert` to see the dependencies that use `proc_macro2`.

```text
$ cargo tree --invert proc-macro2
proc-macro2 v1.0.52
├── const_format_proc_macros v0.2.31
│   └── const_format v0.2.31
│       ├── si_trace_print v0.3.9
│       │   └── super_speedy_syslog_searcher v0.6.66
│       └── super_speedy_syslog_searcher v0.6.66
├── dlopen2_derive v0.2.0
│   └── dlopen2 v0.4.1
│       └── super_speedy_syslog_searcher v0.6.66
...
```

- crate `const_format_proc_macros` depends on crate `proc-macro2`
- crate `dlopen2_derive` depends on crate `proc-macro2`

However, the `cargo tree --invert` command ***does not tell the version of `proc-macro2` required by other crates***.

I'd like to see something like this:

```text
$ cargo tree --invert proc-macro2 --show-versions
proc-macro2 v1.0.52
├── const_format_proc_macros v0.2.31 (proc-macro2 =1.0.52)
│   └── const_format v0.2.31
│       ├── si_trace_print v0.3.9
│       │   └── super_speedy_syslog_searcher v0.6.66
│       └── super_speedy_syslog_searcher v0.6.66
├── dlopen2_derive v0.2.0 (proc-macro2 >=1.0.50)
│   └── dlopen2 v0.4.1
│       └── super_speedy_syslog_searcher v0.6.66
...
```

(the `--show-versions` option was made up)

How can I reveal the various versions of the crate `proc_macro2` required by many project dependencies?

Comment: My first idea is to add `proc-macro2 = "=1.0.63"` to your dependencies. Then, anything that can use it should use it, while anything else should still be on 1.0.52.